# Randomly loosing Internet connection after a few minutes/hours in Linux / NixOS

Tags: linux, networkmanager, dhcp, nixos

I have been dual-booting Linux for about three weeks now, and this issue is keeping me from fully switching because I have to reboot my computer approximately every hour. On Linux, I experience random disconnects from my network. When booting into Windows, I don't get that issue, so it's probably a software issue.

When I am disconnected, the system tries to reconnect, but that never works. After a restart, the problem is gone until it happens again, usually 15 minutes to 2 hours after boot.

When the issue happened, I disabled my wired connection and connected to Wi-Fi. Everything worked, but when I re-enabled the wired connection, it stopped working even though Wi-Fi was still connected.

I also tried:

- Restarting the NetworkManager service
- Setting a fixed IPv4
- Disabled and Enabled Wired Network
- Unplugged and Re-Plugged Network Cable

Everything without success.
A reboot temporarily solves the issue

---

System

```
OS: NixOS 23.05.3701.e9b4b56e5a20 (Stoat) x86_64
Motherboard: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. ROG STRIX B650E-E GAMING WIFI
Kernel: 6.1.54 
CPU: AMD Ryzen 9 7950X
```

lspci

```
07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Controller I225-V (rev 03)
08:00.0 Network controller: MEDIATEK Corp. MT7922 802.11ax PCI Express Wireless Network Adapter
```

Log of NetworkManager from a boot when it happened

```
Okt 16 16:19:13 nixos systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager...
Okt 16 16:19:13 nixos systemd[1]: Started Network Manager.
Okt 16 16:36:01 nixos systemd[1]: Stopping Network Manager...
Okt 16 16:36:01 nixos systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Deactivated successfully.
Okt 16 16:36:01 nixos systemd[1]: Stopped Network Manager.
Okt 16 16:36:01 nixos systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Consumed 196ms CPU time, received 8.6K IP traffic, sent 144B IP traffic.
```

Log of NetworkManager from another broken boot

```
Okt 13 23:29:58 nixos systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager...
Okt 13 23:29:58 nixos systemd[1]: Started Network Manager.
Okt 13 21:59:47 nixos NetworkManager[1671]: <warn>  [1697227187.1589] device (eno1): Activation: failed for connection 'Wired connection 1'
Okt 13 22:00:32 nixos NetworkManager[1671]: <warn>  [1697227232.1589] device (eno1): Activation: failed for connection 'Wired connection 1'
Okt 13 22:01:17 nixos NetworkManager[1671]: <warn>  [1697227277.1583] device (eno1): Activation: failed for connection 'Wired connection 1'
Okt 13 22:02:02 nixos NetworkManager[1671]: <warn>  [1697227322.1592] device (eno1): Activation: failed for connection 'Wired connection 1'
Okt 13 22:06:00 nixos NetworkManager[1671]: <warn>  [1697227560.1590] device (eno1): Activation: failed for connection 'Wired connection 1'
Okt 13 22:06:58 nixos NetworkManager[1671]: <warn>  [1697227618.1576] device (eno1): Activation: failed for connection 'Wired connection 1'
Okt 13 22:07:16 nixos NetworkManager[1671]: <warn>  [1697227636.1919] ndisc[0x13b38e0,"eno1"]: solicit: failure sending router solicitation: Cannot assign requested address (99)
Okt 13 22:07:28 nixos systemd[1]: Stopping Network Manager...
Okt 13 22:07:28 nixos systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Deactivated successfully.
Okt 13 22:07:28 nixos systemd[1]: Stopped Network Manager.
Okt 13 22:07:28 nixos systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Consumed 592ms CPU time, received 4.3K IP traffic, sent 1.3K IP traffic.
```

ip a / when working

```
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a0:36:bc:ba:a5:dd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp7s0
    inet 192.168.10.59/24 brd 192.168.10.255 scope global noprefixroute eno1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2001:9e8:242b:c200:d7a:ee39:3768:342a/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 7193sec preferred_lft 3593sec
    inet6 2001:9e8:242b:c200:d1dc:fab3:1015:82ee/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 7193sec preferred_lft 3593sec
    inet6 fe80::6a74:a49d:4dbd:72c0/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

ip a / when broken

```
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a0:36:bc:ba:a5:dd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp7s0
    inet 192.168.10.59/24 brd 192.168.10.255 scope global noprefixroute eno1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::6a74:a49d:4dbd:72c0/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

lshw -C network / when working

```
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 03
       serial: a0:36:bc:ba:a5:dd
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igc driverversion=6.1.54 duplex=full firmware=1082:8770 ip=192.168.10.59 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:24 memory:fb400000-fb4fffff memory:fb500000-fb503fff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       logical name: wlp8s0
       version: 00
       serial: 86:8c:02:55:26:28
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=mt7921e driverversion=6.1.54 firmware=____000000-20230627143946 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:170 memory:fb200000-fb2fffff memory:fb300000-fb307fff
```

lshw -C network / when broken

```
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 03
       serial: a0:36:bc:ba:a5:dd
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: cap_list ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=igc ip=192.168.10.59 latency=0 multicast=yes
       resources: irq:24 memory:fb400000-fb4fffff memory:fb500000-fb503fff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       logical name: wlp8s0
       version: 00
       serial: 32:93:9c:fa:3b:9b
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=mt7921e driverversion=6.1.54 firmware=____000000-20230627143946 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:170 memory:fb200000-fb2fffff memory:fb300000-fb307fff
```

Comment: perhaps it's a faulty ethernet cable?

Comment: I have already tried but its still happening. Its probably a Software problem because it only happens on Linux

Comment: You could try a different Linux (i.e. a live CD) it may well be the driver

Comment: I’m late in the party, but I remember having this kind of issue with a ubuntu due to a faulty driver that was crashing when encountering some noise in the received packets. Maybe run `dmesg` to see if you see some obvious error messages, usually it is simpler to google this error message to find the fix.